# what is the best way to store bulk of images and MP3 song iOS Sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am doing one iphone app, for that i have to store bulk of MP3 song and images.

can ay one tell me what is the best to store those in terms of performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the image and songs in the application directory. This is best and easy way to handle. Try the following code. it will be help you.

```
//Store Image/Songs files to Application Directory
+(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSData *)data fileName:(NSString *)fileName {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // the path to write file
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        return [data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
}
//Image/songs -  Retrieve from Application Directory
+(NSData *)readFromFile:(NSString *)fileName {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
    if (myData) { 
        return myData;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: this will work if i have less amount of data....if i have more than 1000 songs and 100000 images than is it good way to store them in our application directory

Answer (score 0):

store the MP3 song and images into resources folder of your app project and give the refrences in the sqlite database(because saving large files in sqlite database is not a good practice)

Comment: thanks for your reply...i want to use core data...can you please tell me which one is better in terms of performance...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store all items of large size on the device disk, i.e, Documents directory and store their physical path in core data or sqlite or at least in a plist file so that you can retrieve them as per your convenience.